# Memory limit reached while exectuting a PHP script

Tags: php, hash, iteration, salt, bcrypt

I am currently revising my register script to add PDO and bcrypt. However I run into an error I feel when I try to iterate my hash. I had the rounds initially set to 10000 as I seen tutorials with rounds of 60000+ but that was taking ages. So then I set it to 2 just to test it out and then I got an error :

```
[Tue Dec 25 10:45:07 2012] [error] [] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133431193 bytes) in /var/www/register_script.php on line 28, referer:
```

My entire register script goes as fallows :

```
<?php 
//Minor work needed need to finish user verification 


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name

// Connect to server via PHP Data Object
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

CRYPT_BLOWFISH or die ('No Blowfish found.');

// Creating the salt
$Blowfish_Pre = '$2y$15$';
$Blowfish_End = '$';


$Allowed_Chars =
'/.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$char_len = 63;

$salt_length = 60;
for($round=0;$round<$salt_length;$roundi++)
{
    $salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$char_len)];
}
$bcrypt_salt = $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End;
//Salt creating stops here

//Creating the hash and password
$password = $_POST['password'];

$hashed_password = crypt($password, $bcrypt_salt);
for($round=0; $round<2; $round++)
    {
        $hashed_password = crypt($password, $bcrypt_salt);
    }

// Insert statements with PDO 

try {
        $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `users_blowfish` (username, email, fname, lname, salt, password) 
                               VALUES (:username, :email, :first, :last, :salt, :hash)");

        $query->execute(
                        array(
                        'username' => $_POST['username'],
                        'email' => $_POST['email'], 
                        'first' => $_POST['fname'],
                        'last' => $_POST['lname'],
                        'salt' => $bcrypt_salt,
                        'hash' => $hashed_password
                        )); 
    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    $dbh= null;

    ?>

<html>
    <body>
        <p> 
            Thank you for registering your account. Please wait for administrator approval before doing anything else. Thank you - System Administrator. 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I take out the for statement :

```
$hashed_password = crypt($password, $bcrypt_salt);
for($round=0; $round<2; $round++)
    {
        $hashed_password = crypt($password, $bcrypt_salt);
    }
```

Then it all work. However what confuses me is that I have two for statements the one above ^

and this one :

```
$salt_length = 60;
for($round=0;$round<$salt_length;$roundi++)
{
    $salt .= $Allowed_Chars[mt_rand(0,$char_len)];
}
```

I guess my questions summed up are 
1) Why does the for statement by the hash make the registration extremely slow and the for statement by the salt creation doesn't affect the speed of registration?

Comment: You should not need to manually implement rounds for bcrypt. Don't roll your own, use something that already exists, like http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over `crypt()` makes your page take forever because Blowfish *already* uses multiple hashing rounds, and `crypt()` is what does all of the actual work for the hashing. So if you run `crypt()` multiple times, you're doing all of that work each time.

Looping over adding a few characters to the salt doesn't affect the time because you're not doing any real work - just adding a few characters to a string.

You don't need to loop over `crypt()` multiple times; you're already using bcrypt which includes a work factor.

You also shouldn't need to store the salt separately; the hash produced by bcrypt contains its own salt.

Comment: Ah.. thank you for clarifying that for me I was sort of thinking that but wanted to be reassured. Thanks a lot. And happy holidays :)